# Android: How to keep Default number always even if user wants to delete it, and how to delete default number when user inputs a value?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a simple EditText, which inputs only numbers.

I want to show 0(zero) even if user presses backspace.
Now zero is getting deleted.

Moreover, I need to remove this default zero, when user starts entering values.

How do i achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `android:hint="0"` or in more complex way.. 
You should use `TextWatcher` and override the below three methods. THer you can get the text in the arguments as `CharSequence` in the `beforeTextChanged` and `onTextChanged` methods and in `afterTextChanged` you have `Editable` from where you can get the data in the `EditText`. Write in the desired function as per your logic and it should work like a charm.

```
   editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want:

```
<EditText
    android:hint="0" />
```